Polynomials with non-negative partial backward sums of coefficients
Given a polynomial $p$ of degree $d$, let's denote its coefficients by $a = (a_0,\dots,a_d) \in \mathbb R^{d+1}$, i.e., $p(x) = \sum_{k=0}^d a_k x^k$. In a (non-mathematical) problem I am researching, I encountered polynomials with the property that
$$\tag{1}\label{eq:one}
\sum_{i=k}^d a_i \geq 0, \quad\forall\; 1 \leq k \leq d.$$
In other words, the backward partial sums of the coefficients are non-negative.
An equivalent characterization is $\sum_{i=0}^d a_i \geq \sum_{i=0}^k a_i$ for all $0 \leq k \leq d$, i.e., no partial sum is higher than the full sum of coefficients.
I found that these polynomials are closed under differentiation, but not under integration. Also, one can show that $\max_{x \in [0,1]} p(x) = p(1)$.

 Proceed by induction. The base case $d=0$ is trivial. For $p$ of degree $d \geq 1$ with coefficients $a \in \mathbb R^{d+1}$, introduce $q$ of degree $d-1$ such that $p(x) = a_0 + x q(x)$. Notice that $q$ also fulfills \eqref{eq:one}. We then have for any $x \in [0,1]$, $$p(x) = v_0 + xq(x) \leq v_0 + xq(1) = v_0 + x \sum_{k=1}^d a_k \leq \sum_{k=0}^d a_k = p(1),$$ where the first inequality is due to the induction hypothesis and the second one is due to the fact that $p$ itself fulfils \eqref{eq:one}.

I conjecture that that value is not reached by any point $x \in (0,1)$, unless $p$ is constant, but I haven't been able to prove it yet.
I am curious if this class of polynomials has an established name and perhaps some well-known properties. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Your conjecture is true and can be proven as follows.
\begin{align}
p(x)-p(1) &= \sum_{k=0}^d a_k (x^k-1)
\\
&= (x-1) \sum_{k=1}^d a_k \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} x^j
\\
&= (x-1) \sum_{j=0}^{d-1} x^j \sum_{k=j+1}^d a_k.
\end{align}
Since $x\in (0,1)$ and by the nonnegative partial backward sum property, we conclude that
$$
p(x) \le p(1).
$$
The only way to get equality is if all the partial sums are zero. But then the polynomial is a constant. Therefore, for a nonconstant polynomial the inequality is strict.
